# How to make jQuery click a button when page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, triggers

Here is my code:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<button type="button"  id="SuperWebF1" title="<?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?></span></span></button>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $( "#foo" ).on( "click", function() {
      alert( $( this ).text() );
    });     
        $("#SuperWebF1").click(function(){
        if ($('[name="shipping_method"]', window.parent.document).is(':checked')){
        billing.save();     
        parent.jQuery("#LoadingDiv").show().delay(4300).fadeOut();
        parent.jQuery("#OutDiv").hide().delay(5000).fadeIn();
        parent.jQuery('#OutDiv').removeClass('outerdiv');
        parent.jQuery('#OutDiv').removeClass('outerdivNoAdress');

        setTimeout(function() {
        if( $('#DisplayMe').length ){
           parent.jQuery('#OutDiv').addClass('OuterDiv1000');
        } else {
           parent.jQuery('#OutDiv').addClass('OuterDiv1000No');
        }
        }, 5100);


        parent.jQuery('#InnerIframe').removeClass('FrameCSS');
        parent.jQuery('#InnerIframe').removeClass('FrameCSSNoAdress');
        parent.jQuery('#InnerIframe').addClass('FrameCSS1000');
    }else {
    alert('Моля, изберете начин на доставка!');
    }   

        })
    });
    </script>
```

How can i make jQuery simulate the click on button #SuperWebF1 when page is loaded, is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Try $("#SuperWebF1").click(function(){ /* your code here */}).click();

Comment: why not `$(window).load(function()\{})`

Answer (score 3):

This will work.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#SuperWebF1').trigger( "click" );
});
```

Comment: 1 - I have to add this before `jQuery(document).ready(function($){` or i have to place `$('#SuperWebF1').trigger( "click" )` inside it ?

Comment: When i place `$('#SuperWebF1').trigger( "click" );` in the console i get error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'trigger' of null`

Comment: Whats Jquery version do you have?

Comment: `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>` <---

Comment: Okey, now it is triggering the click but it seems it is repeating the click and it is not stopping. Why ?

Comment: According to Jquery documentation its should works correctly http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ over 1.10.2 jquery version

Comment: Because you tigger click event inside a click function making a bucle, you have to puts the code inside ready function but outside click event

Comment: I think i am doing that, but still i have this problem. Please take a look: http://pastebin.com/WFq9qiiZ

Comment: Absolutelly the same problem. The page is still reloading without stop.

Comment: Click event reload the site ?, in this case click event is triggered all time.

Comment: um... you have bracket mismatch it that code... [FIXED IT]